# Moving Item from a Bucket into another Bucket doesn't keep the item into Bucket structure

Tags: content-editor, powershell, buckets

I have a requirement where I need to get items from a `Bucket` and move them into another `Bucket`.

When I manually move the item using `MoveTo` from the `menu`, it works fine and shows a perfect tree structure in `Bucketable` item format like this.

[image]

But when I try to do that using a `Powershell` script then it shows as a normal item that doesn't come in the `Bucketable` structure. It shows like this.

[image]

The script I am using is this.

```
$destinationItem  = Get-Item "/sitecore/media library/folder1/folder2/Videos"

$rootOfitemsToMove = Get-ChildItem -path "/sitecore/media library/folder1/folder2/folder3/Media Content/2018/05/21/19/52" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -ne 'Bucket' } 

$rootOfitemsToMove | ForEach-Object {
   Move-Item -Path $_.ItemPath -Destination $destinationItem.Paths.FullPath 
}
```

Please let me know if I need to add something to `Powershell` script?

Comment: did you try to sync them after moving them from powershell?

Comment: Wondering why Move-To works without sync and why Move-Item is not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to click on the `sync` button, then it will automatically move into the Bucketable structure. Make sure to click on parent folder and then click on the `sync` button, in your case click on the `Videos` Item.

[image]

Although not sure why we need to do it manually, I can find this way only for now.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav That worked for me

Answer (score 1):

To sync the bucket via PowerShell, you can call the `BucketManager.Sync()` function.

```
[Sitecore.Buckets.Manager.BucketManager]::Sync($destinationItem);
```

Call that after your script is run. You may want to use an `EventDisabler` as this can be an expensive and time consuming call.